# How to ensure only 1 box will be created?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a web application that allows users to duplicate boxes which are  elements.However i am having a slight problem.Everytime when i click one the button to duplicate the box,there will have multiple boxes appearing when there should be just 1 box.How do I fix this issue?

**JQUERY:**

```
function getElem(element) {
var name = $(element).attr('name');
console.log(name);
var dupBtn = document.getElementById('duplicateBox');
$(dupBtn).on('click', function () {
    var check = document.getElementById("box0");
    if (check === null || $(check).attr('name') == null) {
        $(document.getElementById('errorMessage')).text("Please create a box and label it first");
        document.getElementById('errorMessage').style.display = 'block';
        alert("Please create a box and label it first");
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById('errorMessage').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("save").style.pointerEvents = ("auto");
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        $(div).attr('id', 'box' + i);
        $(div).attr('class', 'box');
        $(div).attr('name', name);
        div.style.width = element.style.width;
        div.style.height = element.style.height;
        div.style.border = element.style.border;
        div.style.background = element.style.background;
        $(div).draggable({
            containment: "#canvas"
        });
        $(div).resizable({
            handles: 'ne, se, sw, nw'
        });
        $(div).addClass("Copyof" + name);
        i++;
        $('#boxContain').append(div);
        if (div.getAttribute('name') == null) {

        } else {
            var p = document.createElement("p");
            $(p).text(name);
            $(p).attr('id', "Copyof" + name);
            $(p).attr('class', name);
            $(p).addClass('lbl');
            $(p).addClass($(div).attr('id'));
            $("#existingLbl").append(p);

        }

    }

});
}

    $(div).attr('onclick', 'getElem(this); ');
```

**HTML:**

```
<form name="imageLblForm" method="post" id="imageLblForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" runat="server" action="#">
    <a href="#" id="signOut" onclick="signOut();">Sign out</a>
    <h4 id="errorMessage"></h4>
    <section name="nav" class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><input type="file" id="my_file" name="file1" onchange="" accept=".bmp,.jpg, .png, image/jpg, image/bmp, image/png" style="display:none" multiple /><input type="button" id="openBtn" class="openBtn" value="Open" onclick="document.getElementById('my_file').click();" /></li>
            <li><input type="submit" value="Save" id="save" onclick="document.getElementById('hiddenLink').click(); return false; "><a onclick="document.execCommand('SaveAs','true','<?php if(isset($_FILES['file1'])){echo pathinfo($_FILES['file1']['name'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);}?>.xml');" id="hiddenLink">Save</a></li>
            <li>
                <hr />
            </li>
            <li><button onclick="createBox(); return false;" id="createBoxBtn">Create Rect Box</button></li>
            <li><button onclick="addBox(); return false;" id="duplicateBox">Duplicate Rect Box</button></li>
            <li><button onclick="deleteDiv(); return false;" id="deleteBox">Delete Rect Box</button></li>
            <li><button id="zoomInBtn" onclick="return false;">Zoom In</button></li>
            <li><button id="zoomOutBtn" onclick="return false;">Zoom Out</button></li>
        </ul>
    </section>
    <section name="canvas" class="canvas" id="canvas">
        <div id="boxContain"></div>
        <div class="imageContainer" id="imageContainer">
        </div>

    </section>
    <section id="rightPanel" name="rightPanel" class="rightPanel">
        <div class="label" name="label" id="label">
            <p id="sectionLbl">Box Labels</p>
            <button id="editLblBtn" class="lbls" onclick="return false;">Change Label</button>
            <hr />
            <div id="existingLbl"></div>
            <div id="lblList" class="modal">

                <div class="modal-content">
                    <select id="labels">
                        <option disabled selected value> -- select a label -- </option>
                        <?php
                            $file_lines = file('lbls/predefined_classes.txt');
                            foreach($file_lines as $line){
                                ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $line; ?>">
                            <?php echo $line; ?>
                        </option>

                        <?php

                            }

                        ?>

                    </select>
                    <span class="close">&cross;</span>
                    <input type="button" onclick="return false;" id="submitLbl" value="Select" />
                    <input type="button" onclick="return false;" id="editLbl" value="Edit" />
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="files" name="files" id="files">
            <p>File List</p>

        </div>
    </section>
</form>
```

**I HAVE TRIED:**

```
$('#boxContain').on('click', function (event) {
var dupBtn = document.getElementById('duplicateBox');
var selBox = event.target;
var name = $(selBox).attr('name');
$(dupBtn).on('click', function () {
    var check = document.getElementById("box0");
    if (check === null || $(check).attr('name') == null) {
        $(document.getElementById('errorMessage')).text("Please create a box and label it first");
        document.getElementById('errorMessage').style.display = 'block';
        alert("Please create a box and label it first");

    } else {
        document.getElementById('errorMessage').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("save").style.pointerEvents = ("auto");
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        $(div).attr('id', 'box' + i);
        $(div).attr('class', 'box');
        $(div).attr('name', name);
        div.style.width = event.target.style.width;
        div.style.height = event.target.style.height;
        div.style.border = event.target.style.border;
        div.style.background = event.target.style.background;
        $(div).draggable({
            containment: "#canvas"
        });
        $(div).resizable({
            handles: 'ne, se, sw, nw'
        });
        $(div).addClass("Copyof" + name);
        i++;
        $('#boxContain').append(div);
        if (div.getAttribute('name') == null) {

        } else {
            var p = document.createElement("p");
            $(p).text(name);
            $(p).attr('id', "Copyof" + name);
            $(p).attr('class', name);
            $(p).addClass('lbl');
            $(p).addClass($(div).attr('id'));
            $("#existingLbl").append(p);

        }
    }

}); //end of dupBtn onclick
}); //end of boxContain onclick
```

The codes are like this.When user creates a box,it will have a onclick attribute which calls the getElem() function.In this function,when the user clicks Duplicate Box button,the selected box will be duplicated and only ONE box should appear.But i keep having multiple boxes appearing.Please help me..Thank you.

Comment: Could you please post your HTML code. Thanks :)

Comment: @Ekown hi i have updated my post.But the box is created only when user clicks on "Create Box" button

Comment: @AdminTester Could you please add a working code snippet it will be helpful in understanding the problem.

Comment: @WebSwami I have a JSFiddle here but i dont understand why it is not working when ive already included the essential codes.https://jsfiddle.net/3yps2570/6/

Comment: Sadly. I can't help if i can't see the problem.

Comment: @Ekown I am only able to describe the problem..I am using event.target to get the selected <div> that i want to duplicate and only 1 duplication should appear but instead I get more than 1 duplication.

Comment: How many exact duplications is being added?

Comment: @AdminTester so as per my understanding you want only one div to be created and after that only one duplication is allowed and after that duplication of div is not allowed, is this correct understanding?

Comment: @Ekown based on how many times the selected box is clicked.When testing how a user will click on the box,click 1 to drag.click 2 to resize once,click 4 to dblclick and assign a label(not impt),then final click 5 to select the box to duplicate.So a total of 5 duplications.

Comment: @WebSwami uhm there should only be one duplication appearing each time the user tries to duplicate the selected box.So..they should be able to duplicate again.But only 1 box should appear each time they duplicate

Comment: Let us chat here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188461/how-to-ensure-only-1-box-will-be-created

Comment: @Ekown sorry i do not have enough reputation to view the conversation in the chat room

Comment: Okay, it seems that the problem might be in the event listeners for the boxes.

Comment: @Ekown How should I add the event listener?I have tried this method before changing to the method stated in my post.But I still face the same issue.Let me add the codes in..I apologise for not adding it earlier..

Comment: Try using the id of the duplicated box instead of the element of the box itself as the anchor for the event listener like `$($(div).attr('class')).attr('onclick', 'getElem(this); ')`

Comment: @Ekown but to use the id..?If I have created multiple boxes,how do i identify which id the user has selected?

Comment: Well, you were setting the id for the div boxes after you were creating them and incrementing it like `box0, box1, box2` so the id of the boxes are different with each other.

Comment: @Ekown that is correct.But I am not understanding how to use the answer you have provided?Could you explain how it works?Thank you

Comment: @Ekown the boxes are not appearing anymore as it is not calling the function getElem();

Comment: Oops, I mistyped. You should assign the div class in a separate variable and then use that variable to attach the event listener. Like `$('.' + divClass).attr('onclick', 'getElem(this));`.